# How to convert this XML into a hidden form field?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I convert this XML

```
<products>
  <entry>
    <name handle="foo1">Foo1</name>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name handle="foo2">Foo2</name>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name handle="foo3">Foo3</name>
  </entry>
</products>
```

into this HTML

```
<input value="fields[address,foo1,foo2,foo3]" />
```

with XSLT?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="input">
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:text>fields[address,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="products/entry/name">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@handle"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@handle"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
<input value="fields[address,foo1,foo2,foo3]"/>
```